# Spring cloud netflix - Eureka - JMXMonitor Warning

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am using spring cloud netflix to build micro service application, I'm using Eureka Servers (Peer to Peer Communication) and my microservices register with the eureka server. All works as expected.

But in the logs I see below warning every 10-15 minutes.

I did some research and my understanding is that it's Monitoring the registry backed by JMX. Does anyone ever seen this issue or can anyone give some good suggestions on what will be best solution to fix. Can we disable this monitoring?

```
WARN 1 --- [      Finalizer] c.netflix.servo.jmx.JmxMonitorRegistry   : Unable to un-register Monitor:MonitorConfig{name=Discovery-PeerNodeClient- 172.17.0.1, tags=class=NamedConnectionPool, policy=DefaultPublishingPolicy}

javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: com.netflix.servo:name=Discovery-PeerNodeClient- 172.17.0.1_Reuse,class=NamedConnectionPool,type=COUNTER,id=Discovery-PeerNodeClient- 172.17.0.1
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:427)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:546)
at com.netflix.servo.jmx.JmxMonitorRegistry.unregister(JmxMonitorRegistry.java:123)
at com.netflix.servo.DefaultMonitorRegistry.unregister(DefaultMonitorRegistry.java:143)
at com.netflix.servo.monitor.Monitors.unregisterObject(Monitors.java:199)
at com.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool.shutdown(NamedConnectionPool.java:188)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.shutdown(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:293)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.finalize(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:165)
at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(System.java:1213)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:98)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:34)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:210)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and after the upgrade to spring 1.3 the service (in my case the eureka server) even refuses to start :-(